# PySimpleGUI show user selection in window

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a calendar button and a file browser button in a single window.

When a date is selected from the calendar, I want the date selected to show next to the button. When the user selects a file, I want the path to be shown in the input box. How can I accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Date to Start Summing')],
          [sg.In(key='-CAL-', visible=False),
           sg.CalendarButton('Calendar', target='-CAL-', pad=None, font=('MS Sans Serif', 10, 'bold'),
                             button_color=('red', 'white'), format='%m/%d/%Y')],
          [sg.Text('Filename')],
          [sg.In(key='-DIR-', visible=False),
           sg.Input(size=(20, None)), sg.FileBrowse('Browse', target='-DIR-')],
          [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]]


window = sg.Window('Data Collector', layout, grab_anywhere=False, size=(400, 280), return_keyboard_events=True,
                   finalize=True)

event, values = window.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Date to Start Summing', key='-CALOUTPUT-', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold')), sg.Text(key='-CAL-', size=(10, None), font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))],
          [sg.CalendarButton('Calendar', target='-CAL-', pad=None, font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), format='%m/%d/%Y')],
          [sg.Text('Filename', key='-FOUTPUT-', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))],
          [sg.In( visible=False),
           sg.Input(key='-DIR-', size=(20, None), font=('Arial', 10, 'bold')), sg.FileBrowse('Browse', target='-DIR-', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))],
          [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]]


window = sg.Window('Data Collector', layout, grab_anywhere=False, size=(400, 280), return_keyboard_events=True,
                   finalize=True)

event, values = window.read()
```